# How do add span on my table echo?

Tags: php

Hello i just new to coding but i don't know how to add span on my table on my echo every-time keep moving the table i need help how to do syntax on  my code

here is my original code for my table

```
<td><span id="name<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><span id="email<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
<td><span id="username<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
<td><span id="level<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
```

this my other table for my edit but everytime i press the button it does not display any value in my edit

```
<td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["username"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["email"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["level"].'</td>
<td><a style="cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn-info edit" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true" ></span></a> || <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

what im trying to get how do i put id on this echo output to direct it to my button showing the value of id return all the value on that id.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $output .= '
    <tr>
      <td>'.$row["name"].'</td> <-- how do i add <span>,put id on this rows 
      <td>'.$row["username"].'</td> or how to add id on this table 
      <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["level"].'</td>
      <td>
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn-info edit" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true" ></span></a> || <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>';
}
echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Missing closing `</span>`s in your original code

Comment: Unless you have some javascript you are not showing you just have two `<a>`s that look like a button but do nothing

Comment: trying to get <span> onto the <td> '.row["name"].'</td> but instead it only move my table row what im trying to get is having my name,username,email have id value so that when i press the button it would display correct value instead of nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your `$output` with `<span>`s in them:

```
$output .= '
<tr>
  <td><span id="name'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["name"].'</span></td>
  <td><span id="username'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["username"].'</span></td>
  <td><span id="email'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["email"].'</span></td>
  <td><span id="level'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["level"].'</span></td>
  <td>
    <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn-info edit" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true" ></span></a> || <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
  </td>
</tr>';
```